# Should we post on games that are still in Beta (Private or Public)?

Tags: discussion

I'm a member of the Solforge beta. It's a great game, and I'm beginning to run into a few things where I could ask Q's on Arq (regarding tactics, as game stability is obviously still an ongoing issue)

What's the policy on asking questions of games that are still in Public/Private beta.

Comment: see also [when is a game publicly available?](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/5539/27134)

Comment: Ah, that's the cookie, thanks Kalina!

Comment: Is there an NDA? No? Then it's probably fine. (If there is, it's _your_ problem.)